# Instance var in event handler is always initial value

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, event-handling

I have a problem with accessing an instance var in an event handler.

When I'm trying to access an instance var in an event handler, it seems to always have the initial value, even though the value has changed since.

In my simple demo app, I have a horizontal slider and a UIImageView:

[image: manifest screenshot]

`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

    var canvas:MyCanvas?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.canvas = MyCanvas()
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        self.canvas!.sliderValueUpdated(sender.value);
    }
}
```

`MyCanvas.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyCanvas : UIImageView {

    // the var I care about
    var sliderValue:Float = 0.5;

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func sliderValueUpdated (newValue:Float) {
        self.sliderValue = newValue;

        // prints the correct value
        println(self.sliderValue)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        // always prints initial value, 0.5
        println(self.sliderValue)
    }
}
```

I set `MyCanvas.swift` as custom class for the UIImageView.

So when I adjust the slider, it prints out the correct value for `self.sliderValue`. However, when I'm firing a touch event after that, it always prints out the initial value, `0.5` instead of the slider value.

Why is that?

How do I fix this?

Comment: I believe you have two different instances of MyCanvas. Have you tried to set it as the Custom Class of your UIImageView?

Comment: I believe debugging can always fix your issue.

Comment: @cmatsuoka you're right. ``MyCanvas`` is instantiated twice. (once in the code the other time by setting it as custom class of the UIImage view. this is why the value never seems to update. I fixed it by removing ``self.canvas = MyCanvas()``

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you don't have an `IBOutlet` to your canvas. By initializing the canvas in `viewDidLoad`, the initialized canvas is not actually on the screen (you would have to add it to the subviews). Thus, your `sliderValueChanged IBAction` is not actually updating the `sliderValue` property of the `MyCanvas` on the screen. I recommend setting your `UIImageView` in the storyboard as a `MyCanvas` class and making an `IBOutlet` to that `MyCanvas` object in your `Storyboard`. Then remove the `canvas = MyCanvas()` from your `viewDidLoad` function.